# Brauer groups, Milnor k theory and group cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology, brauer-group

Can anyone suggest some basic material for learning connections between Brauer groups, Milnor k theory and group cohomology. I am an undergraduate. So, I find most of the sources available very hard.

Comment: You want to learn the connections. Do you already know the subjects separatey?

Comment: I know just the definitions of Brauer groups and Milnor k groups and some homological algebra. I know stuff like Hilbert 90th theorem. But, still I want to know some basic things. The most basic source I could find was notes by Sridharan given at ETH Zurich. But, I am looking for more basic sources .

Comment: There aren't many basic sources becausse it is not a basic subject.

Comment: may be...because i have tried so hard but still cannot find a basic source.

Comment: As I wrote, it is **not** a basic subject in any possible sense of the term.

Answer (score 2):

A rather nice approach is in Pierce's *Associative Algebras* book. You will not find there anything about $K$-theory, but you can safely leave that for later.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything else you can suggest? I particularly want to study connections between Milnor k2 groups, 2 torsion of Brauer groups and group cohomology.

Comment: Milnor's book on K-theory.

Comment: ok..thanks..i will check that.